# Why is my drop-shadow not working on parent element?

Tags: css, clip-path, dropshadow

I'm making an origami butterfly, placing trapezoid shapes on top of others, to create an illusion of folded paper. However, for some reason, the filter:drop-shadow is not working on the clip-path part-1 and part-2, even though I have wrapped around them the wrapper parents and applied drop shadow there.

I have trouble figuring this out. Appreciate any help. Thank you!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.frame {
  width: 65vw;
  height: 65vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 13px 2px #5d5d5d30;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(3vw);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fff1eb 0%, #ace0f9 100%);
}

.holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.part-1-wrap {
  filter: drop-shadow(9px 5px 10px rgba(black, 0.2)) drop-shadow(-9px 5px 10px rgba(black, 0.2));
  position: absolute;
  left: 0vw;
  top: 0vw;
  z-index: 6;
}

.part-1 {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 67.3% 2.5%, 77% 100%, 35.1% 88.8%);
  background: #da1f1f;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 16vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vw;
  left: 6vw;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.part-2-wrap {
  filter: drop-shadow(9px 5px 10px rgba(black, 0.2)) drop-shadow(-9px 5px 10px rgba(black, 0.2));
  position: absolute;
  left: 0vw;
  top: 0vw;
  z-index: 3;
}

.part-2 {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 67.3% 2.5%, 77% 100%, 35.1% 88.8%);
  background: #da1f1f;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 16vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vw;
  left: 22vw;
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="part-1-wrap">
      <div class="part-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part-2-wrap">
      <div class="part-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part-3-wrap">
      <div class="part-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part-4-wrap">
      <div class="part-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part-5-wrap">
      <div class="part-5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the rgba() you are using is a SASS function not a CSS one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rgba` takes 4 parameters `(RED, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA)`

You used it like this:

```
  filter: drop-shadow(9px 5px 10px rgba(black, 0.2)) drop-shadow(-9px 5px 10px rgba(black, 0.2));
```

Also using two drop-shadow will take the total sum of them, you won't have two shadows.

for example :

```
filter: drop-shadow(9px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)) drop-shadow(-9px -5px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
```

This will make no shadow at all.

You should use one drop shadow per element like this:

```
filter: drop-shadow(9px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
```

Check the snippet:

Note that I changed `0.2` to `0.8` to see the effect.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.frame {
  width: 65vw;
  height: 65vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 13px 2px #5d5d5d30;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(3vw);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fff1eb 0%, #ace0f9 100%);
}

.holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.part-1-wrap {
  filter: drop-shadow(9px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8));
  position: absolute;
  left: 0vw;
  top: 0vw;
  z-index: 6;
}

.part-1 {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 67.3% 2.5%, 77% 100%, 35.1% 88.8%);
  background: #da1f1f;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 16vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vw;
  left: 6vw;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.part-2-wrap {
  filter: drop-shadow(9px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8));
  position: absolute;
  left: 0vw;
  top: 0vw;
  z-index: 3;
}

.part-2 {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 67.3% 2.5%, 77% 100%, 35.1% 88.8%);
  background: #da1f1f;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 16vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vw;
  left: 22vw;
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="part-1-wrap">
      <div class="part-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part-2-wrap">
      <div class="part-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part-3-wrap">
      <div class="part-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part-4-wrap">
      <div class="part-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="part-5-wrap">
      <div class="part-5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
```

instead of

```
rgba(black, 0.2)
```